# CSS3 transitions messing up the layout?

Tags: css-transitions

So I am trying to come to terms with CSS3 and thought I would start on transitions as it would give my layouts a nice effect, I used the code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

div
{
width:40px;
height:60px;
opacity:0.4;
background:black;
transition:all 2s;
-moz-transition:all 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition:all 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition:all 2s; /* Opera */
}

div:hover
{
width:90px;
opacity:0.9;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<u><b><center>TEST</center></b></u>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
<br>
```

whenever I use that code the layout completely messes up leaving me with nothing pretty much, just everything a transition and in the wrong positions. Can anyone find anything wrong with the coding?

[EDIT] This is what happens - http://testingforsite.weebly.com/

Comment: Is this a valid value for transitions? `all`

Comment: It could be because you put a `<center>` inside `<b>` and `<u>`. It should be the other way around. (Well, you should use CSS.)

Comment: Thanks for that minitech! That fixed a small problem (:

I am still left with this though - http://testingforsite.weebly.com/

Comment: Works fine for me! Which browser are you using?

Comment: Still works fine for me. Do you mean the problem is that it makes all the other `<div>`s on the page transition?

Comment: I'm thinking so! Not sure on how to change that though.

Comment: If you only want to target one `<div>`, give it an `id` and use `#my-id` to select it. If you want to target many, use `class` and `.my-class` to select it.

Comment: Would you be able to help me further? I know the basics of using <div> but really don't understand putting it to use in this code.

Answer (score 1):

Giving your div an id will help out. Because if you write it like this, CSS changes all the divs on your website.

HTML:

```
<div id="div-of-transition"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#div-of-transition{
   transition:all 2s;
   -moz-transition:all 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
   -webkit-transition:all 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
   -o-transition:all 2s; /* Opera */
```

This will only change the div you named `div-of-transition`